# Passing params from view to controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, parameter-passing

This is my view code

_navigation.html.erb

```
<% if User.current.allowed_to?(:view_repository, @project) -%>
    <div style="float: left; width: auto; padding-right: 1%">  
    <%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'GerarVersao')%>
    </div>
|
<% end -%>
```

exec_client is my function in controller side. Below the following code:

gerar_versao_controller.rb

```
def exec_client(branch)
hostname = 'localhost'
port = 8522
s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)
s.puts "MSG_RV"
s.puts branch.to_s
s.close
end
```

This code doesn't works. I get this error:

**ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):**

**The Question is:** How do I to pass the param Branch to my controller function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the :with parameter
Look at this example
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/remote_function#529-Example

Comment: It doesn't works. Don't you have any example for my case? I tried to use this, but when I click on the button, nothing happens.